# TeamCity Nuget feed viewing

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

So maybe I'm a little bit confused about how a nuget server works and the specifics of nugets in general.

I am setting up octopus deploy and TeamCity for my company and have run into a bit of a snag. I am trying to set up a deployment where I deploy a website and a service in the same release, however, Octopus can't seem to find the nuget package. It throws the following error:

> Could not find any packages with ID 'PackageName' in the feed 'octopus://'

I am able to see the package when I test the feed in octopus, and I verified that I am using the correct ID in teamcity. Basically what I've been trying to research is how I can view all of my nugets in the feed. Is that a thing? I am using TeamCity as the Nuget server and I know with octopus you can view all packages that have been pushed to its repository. Am I able to view all packages in the TeamCity Nuget server? I want to verify that my package is there.

Comment: If you login to the Octopus server and go to library page (http://localhost/app#/library), you will be able to view all the Packages that you have created, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess that would be for any nuget package that was pushed to the octopus server or uploaded by me. I am currently using TeamCity as an external feed and not pushing anything to Octopus. When I go to test the external feed from "app#/library/feeds/feeds-teamcity/test" I am able to pull up packages if I search for them. I guess what I was really looking for is a way to see a listing much like the library option in octopus. Is this possible from the TeamCity interface?

Comment: according to https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NuGet#NuGet-UsingTeamCityasNuGetServer   click Enable on the Administration | NuGet Settings | NuGet Server page

Answer (score 1):

In order for Octopus to be able to publish the package, it needs it to be set to build an [OctoPack](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack).

To get this working, use the NuGet package manager for the project in question and add a reference to 'OctoPack'.

Bear in mind that if you have a Visual Studio solution containing several packages and you want several of these to be deployable packages you will have to add OctoPack to each project you want as a deployable package.

Answer (score 0):

Include Octopack in the project to build the nuget package.

Use this parameter with MSBuild to automatically push the package to the destination nuget gallery after the build is complete.

/p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://my-nuget-server/api/v2/package